# i am trying to run a thread in python but no output is seen

Tags: python, multithreading, file-handling

This is running on a for loop;

```
for something in something:
   if qf.isAlive:
            qf.join()
            qf.run()
            print('File writing thread id alive and now running')
        else:
            qf.start()
            print('File writing thread started')
```

and I defined these two codes out of the loop;

```
qf = threading.Thread(target=add_to_file)
qf.setDaemon = True
```

and this is the function for writing the file;

```
def add_to_file():
    with open('queue.txt', 'w+') as f:
       f.write(str(list(queue)))
       f.close()
```

I am not getting any ouput as 'File writing thread is alive...' and also the queue.txt file is empty
please help me in this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here.  First of all, the print statements are probably buffered, you can do something like this:

```
import sys
...and then after your loop...
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Secondly, although you haven't shown in your code what the variable `queue` points to, if it's related to those threads, note that `print` doesn't return anything, so it will be empty.